# How to open a series of csv files, edit and re-save with a revised string variable in the filename

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, filenames

I have a series of csv files that each have several columns. I want to open each file, delete some columns,  rename the last column, and save the revised file under a new, similar name,  and repeat this ~2500 times

The basic open, edit, save aspects does work for a single, hardcoded filename (both old and new). The problem I'm having is in iterating it. I have a "print.head(2)"in the middle to see if the dataframe is being edited (it's not) and I get various errors in the writing to csv portion, depending on how I've tried to type the code (parenthesis, versus quotes, versus double quotes, etc)

```
import pandas as pd 


f = open("D:\Latest  programs &  data  that work -in IDLE-/1st 495 symbols.csv", "r")


for symbol in f.readlines():

symbol = symbol.strip()


url_part1 = symbol
url_part2 = ".csv"
url = url_part1 + url_part2 
print(url)  # this part works - I get a long list of them

# this is where the problems start
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col ="Close")


df.drop(["Volume", "Date", "Open", "High", "Low"], axis = 1, inplace = True)


df.rename(columns = {'Close':symbol})

df.head()

url_part0 = "edited"
final_url = url_part0 + url

df.to_csv(r'D:\Latest  programs &  data  that work -in IDLE-/name')
```

The "in process outputs are the old file name (CNNE.csv) followed by the top 2 rows 
CNNE
43.24

These are just in-process indicators to show things are functioning. (currently, I DO get the old  file name, but that is all)

The intended "real" output is a collection of new csv files with the only column of daily values being called by the symbol name sand a coupe rows of data.

The error I  get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/Latest  programs &  data  that work -in IDLE-/Column deletion tool revised for stack v2.py", line 19, in <module>
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col ="Close")
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 463, in _read
data = parser.read(nrows)
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1154, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2124, in read
index, names = self._make_index(data, alldata, names)
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1568, in _make_index
index = self._get_simple_index(alldata, columns)
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1600, in _get_simple_index
i = ix(idx)
File "C:\Users\my admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1595, in ix
raise ValueError("Index {col} invalid".format(col=col))
ValueError: Index Close invalid
```

Comment: i think the forward slash here is invalid = `df.to_csv(r'D:\Latest  programs &  data  that work -in IDLE-/name')` change `IDLE/` to ` IDLE\ `

Comment: error shows that it has problem with `"Close"` in `pd.read_csv(url, index_col ="Close")` - maybe you open file which doesn't have column with name `Close`. Try without `index_col="Close"` to see if it can be problem. Or open file in text editor to see what you get. Maybe there is error message or warning for you.

Comment: Datanovice - I'll tinker with that. Thanks!
furas - when I run this portion of the script with a fixed filename (such as CNNE.csv) the it works; there is a column in the unaltered csv called "Close", and part of this script changes it to "symbol". That said, thanks! I will make sure the code hasn't changed from the single symbol test code, to this longer iterated version.

Comment: For reference, the initial csv files look like this:
timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume

2019-08-05,28.7000,28.8900,28.3400,28.6000,213101

2019-08-02,29.1500,29.3200,28.2200,29.1200,215782

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons the dataframe is not getting updated because the statement where you are renaming the columns is not entirely correct. Here's how it should look like:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'Close':symbol})
```

You have to assign it back to the dataframe variable or do it place like below:

```
df.rename(columns = {'Close':symbol}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I had the  "inplace = True" in an earlier version, and can't recall why it changed. (I am horrible at working with expressions like that. I'll try it.

Comment: OK, I tried adding the inplace=True, and no change. (error test is identical to what is posted here) Note, the "url" in df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col ="Close") is a string variable, that has been created earlier on. Should this "url" be in quotes? braces? I am lost here, as well.

Comment: No. url is a variable and should NOT be passed inside quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I had to put "close" into paranthesis, and it works: 
  df.rename(columns={'close':(symbol)}, inplace=True) I STILL  can't get it to save the df with t he file name (symbol).csv.